# Как сделать такой фон на сайте?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот такой фон через css можно сделать?
пробовал `transform:rotate()`, но тогда блок поворачивается и остаются пробелы по краям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `transform: skewY();`

```css
.wrapper {
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-2deg);
}
.wrapper>div {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(2deg);
}
.green {
  background-color: #afa;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffa;  
}
.blue {
  background-color: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper green">
  <div>контент</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper yellow">
  <div>контент</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper blue">
  <div>контент</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А все браузеры поддерживают этот метод?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility